# Accessing the content value from within 3 classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, subclass

So I have a dropdown box with values "No" and "Yes" but it will not property display it when selected. It just comes up as blank. No matter what I choose, I want it to display what I have chosen, either "Yes" or "No".

So I got the class names for everything that I need.

For the selected value that is being displayed in the dropdown box is:

```
<a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="select2-chosen">No</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
    .....
</a>
```

The dropdown box html code is:

```
<ul class="select2-results">
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
          <div class="select2-result-label">No</div>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
          <div class="select2-result-label">Yes</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I want to access the values of *select2-result-label* and set them to the *select2-chosen* content value. I tried doing it, but it's giving me an error in FireBug.

Here's what I did so far... What am I doing wrong?

```
function testFunc() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-chosen");
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted")
            .getElementsByClassName("select2-result-label");
    x[0].innerHTML = y;
}
```

Comment: From the comments of the question below, am I right in assuming you are unable to change the javascript? Also your code is vanilla js, are you not using jquery? (I only ask as you have tagged it)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure... I'm a first-time user and I'm not sure if it's jQuery or not...

Comment: You are using JavaScript in your current code. In future I suggest only including `javascript` as a tag, not `jquery` as people answering your question will assume you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `getElementsByClassName` in the wrong context. This function merely returns all elements that have **any** of the specified class names.

As `select2-highlighted` is only assigned to a selected element, it's the only class you should care about. Making these changes should help:

```
function testFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-chosen");
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-highlighted")[0].getElementsByClassName("select2-result-label");
  x[0].innerHTML = y[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: So should I get rid of that lengthy class name and just use "select2-highlighted"?

Comment: Yes, then it only selects the element that is selected

Answer (score 1):

It should work with

```
x[0].innerHTML = y[0].innerHTML;
```

But why did you make it so f=difficult for yourself? Why didn't you use radio buttons, for instance? And why didn't you use id's?

Comment: Sorry again. But it's saying TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)getElementsByClassName is not a function

Comment: It should be: var y = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted")[0].getElementsByClassName("select2-result-label"); You are better off using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
replace

```
"var y = document.get..."
```

with

```
"var y = document.getElementsByClassName("select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted")[0].children[0].innerHTML;"
```

=========================================================================
Try something like this to make use of radio buttons, as Sylvia suggested:

```js
window.setAnswer = function(dom) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (el in els)
    {
        if (els[el].checked)
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = els[el].nextSibling.nodeValue;               
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="setAnswer()">Yes</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="setAnswer()">No</input><br>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the html code. It's locked and I need to find a way to get around this and I'm only given with what I have so far... Thank you though. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Where are you calling testFunc() ?